# UITableView without UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to create a UITableView without a UIViewController?

I am looking for at way to have a UITableView in a Framework as a standalone UIView. I am able to separate DataSources out, but that still require me to have a UIViewController. How can I feed a UITableView without a UIViewController?

Thanks for any directions

Comment: Any object can be a table view's datasource/delegate, it doesn't have to be a view controller.

Comment: "Is it possible to create a UITableView without a UIViewController?" Of course. "How can I ..." How can you _not_? What's the problem?

Comment: Right, but the TableView needs to be in a ViewController before if can feed the table.

Comment: Well that isn't actually true, but if whoever is using your framework wants to put your tableview in a view controller then they can do so, it doesn't require any work from you.

Comment: A view controller doesn't "feed" a table. A data source / delegate "feeds" a table. There's a big difference.

Comment: I might totally be missing something here, but there is no dataSource on a UITableView.

Comment: "but there is no dataSource on a UITableView" Of course there is. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614955-datasource

Comment: There's a class called UITableViewController. Use that

Comment: There is if you make it a `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the problem that you want the table view to populate itself with data, without any need for an extraneous object? Make a UITableView subclass and turn the table view itself (or some helper object held as a property — that would be better) into the table view's delegate and data source.

Minimal example:

```
class MyTableView : UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
    }
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        self.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = ["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is what I am after. Would I then just implement UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate on the UITable?

Comment: Right, this was not a well thought question :-) Thanks